# Java Object to JSON through correct configuration for ObjectMapper with getSerializationConfig() approach

Tags: json, jackson

I am working with `Jackson` version `2.8.7`

I have a `Person` object that is printed in the following way:

```
object: Persona [id=087, nombre=Leonardo, apellido=Jordan, fecha=Sun Jul 05 00:00:00 PET 1981]
```

Observe the date part `Sun Jul 05 00:00:00 PET 1981`

I did a research from these two valuable posts about how serialize an **object** (entity) and a **Date** object into JSON format:

- [Converting Java objects to JSON with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786129/converting-java-objects-to-json-with-jackson)
- [How to make JsonGenerator pretty-print Date and DateTime values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442966/how-to-make-jsongenerator-pretty-print-date-and-datetime-values)

When I use:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(dateFormat);

ObjectWriter ow = objectMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Observe two things:

- `objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(dateFormat);`
- `writer()`

I always get:

```
json: {
  "id" : "087",
  "nombre" : "Leonardo",
  "apellido" : "Jordan",
  "fecha" : 363157200000
}
```

Observe the `363157200000` value and without quotes. 
Therefore it did not work.

But If use:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(dateFormat);

ObjectWriter ow = objectMapper.writer(dateFormat).withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Observe two things:

- `//objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(dateFormat);` commented
- `writer(dateFormat)` the argument

I always get:

```
json: {
  "id" : "087",
  "nombre" : "Leonardo",
  "apellido" : "Jordan",
  "fecha" : "1981-07-05"
}
```

Now works.

1. Why the first approach did not work?
2. What is the correct configuration for the first approach to get the expected behaviour?

I am more interested in the first approach in case I need apply more features through the `getSerializationConfig().with(...)` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach does not work because **with()** creates and returns a new SerializationConfig, so it is not applied to the objectMapper instance that you are using. This is the javadocs for that method:

```
/**
 * Fluent factory method that will construct and return a new configuration
 * object instance with specified features enabled.
 */
```

This method can be used when you want to reuse the configuration of one ObjectMapper instance for another one. With the **with()** method you can specify any difference you want to apply to the copy of the config.

For example, here we are using the configuration of the mapper 1, with a different date format, for the mapper2. The mapper 1 is not changed.

```
    ObjectMapper mapper2 = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper2.setConfig(mapper1.getSerializationConfig().with(otherDateFormat));
```

In order to apply the dateformat to every case you can use **setDateFormat(DateFormat)**:

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just curious when is mandatory or is useful use the `objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().with(...)` approach. If you can add that answer to your current answer would be great. Thanks gain.

Comment: Basically it is used to reuse the configuration from a mapper into another one, being able to change this configuration at the same time. I added a simple example. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot by the explanation. Now has more sense.

Comment: Just curious how that `mapper2` should be used later. I mean, your code explain how create it, but not how and where use it. I understand `mapper1` is reused.

Comment: `mapper2` would be used like any other different ObjectMapper, totally independent to `mapper1`. The use of it could be when you need different mappers depending on the situation (different points of integration with different JSON structures coming, for example), and this is a simple way to share the same base configuration. Anyway, this is a capability I never needed to use.